# Uitextview dataDetectors callback

Tags: ios7, uitextview, datadetectortypes

How can i determine if a uitextview has data that is being flagged by the datadetector?

I am a building an ios chat feature and want to transform incoming messages that have phonenumbers emails, etc. into secure text.

I see textview can detect these items but once they have been detected, is there a callback or a delegate method that gets called so i can transform the text there?

Answer (score 0):

You should get a UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification and a textViewDidEndEditing: delegate method call.